# Represent all bits of hexadecimal number in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net

In C# the following works:

```
UInt32 MyUInt32 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
UInt64 MyUInt64 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

But the equivalent VB generates error `BC30439: Constant expression not representable in type 'ULong'`:

```
Dim MyUInt32 As UInt32 = &HFFFFFFFF ' Error BC30439
Dim MyUInt64 As UInt64 = &HFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF ' Also fails
```

Changing the initialisation value to the largest value representable as a signed integer (i.e. Int32 or Int64) works:

```
Dim MyUInt32 As UInt32 = &H7FFFFFFF ' Works
Dim MyUInt64 As UInt64 = &H7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF ' Also works
```

Is there any way to get that final (32nd or 64th) bit in VB?

Comment: The type of the variable doesn't affect the type of the number literal. It looks like `&H` is a signed literal. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters#hexadecimal-binary-and-octal-literals) say `You can also define an integer literal as a hexadecimal (base 16) number with the &H prefix`

Comment: Open up `Project -> Properties -> Compile`, click the `Advanced Compile Option` button and tick `Remove integer overflow checks`. -- You have the same setting as C# now (which has the same option, but *inverted*).

Comment: @Jimi: Thanks, that works. If you knock that into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @Jimi I don't think this is the best approach, also see my answer below.

Comment: @Craig The OP is comparing C# behavior with VB.Net's. I just suggested how make it even. Is C#'s default behavior *not right*? Or *not the best approach*? Or maybe it's the way VB.Net infers the Type that is *questionable*? Because, this: `&HFFFFFFFF` is clearly an `UInt32`, not an `Int32` Type. C# infers it like that.

Comment: @Jimi I agree that this is a pretty thorny case.  While I don't like the VB behavior, the more I think about it, the less certain I am that there's a good alternative that doesn't introduce its own problems.  Probably the best choice would be to always consider a hex constant as unsigned int rather than signed int (and live with overflow errors if you try to assign &HFFFFFFFF (UI) to a regular `Integer`).  I'd guess that as implemented, the representation as hex is independent of the literal type assignment/inference.

Comment: Really, that goes for octal and binary constants too.  All of them should be treated as unsigned, and force the user to specifically indicate when they should be signed, since 99% of the time (unscientific estimate) they're only going to be used in an unsigned context.

Comment: My own view is that the C/C++/C# behaviour of treating `0x` literals as unsigned is more natural to developers. Both ways of dealing with this issue are fine, though "explicitly indicating intent" feels cleaner than "turning off overflow checks" (which has the feel of "yikes, what else is **that** doing??). Why doesn't VB just behave like C# as @Craig suggests: Treat `&H` as unsigned (and leave "overflow checking" as a separate issue)?

Comment: Well, that's not turning off overflow checks, just **Integer** overflow checks. Integers overflow by turning negative. Unsigned integers don't overflow, just get to UInt32.MaxValue. So `Dim MyUInt32_1 As UInt32 = &HFFFFFFFF Dim MyUInt32_2 As UInt32 = &HFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` will have the same value (`uint.MaxValue`). Not disputing your preferences in any way, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your literals.  By default, integer literals are treated as signed.  If you want something other than the default, then (as can happen in other languages) you can tell the compiler.

The correct way to do this is:

```
Dim MyUInt32 As UInt32 = &HFFFFFFFFUI
Dim MyUInt64 As UInt64 = &HFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUL
```

Note the "UI" and "UL" on the end of the constants: these tell the compiler that they should be treated as unsigned int and unsigned long, respectively.

It's more common to need to do this when you want a shorter-than-default constant, e.g. specifying that a constant is a `Single` or a `Short` instead of a `Double` or an `Integer`.

(You can argue, and I probably wouldn't disagree, that in this specific case, the compiler should recognize what you want to do and automatically change the literals to unsigned, just as it automatically treats the longer one as a `Long` instead of an `Integer`.)

Comment: Works nicely. This seems cleaner as the developer makes their intent clear that the literal should be "unsigned". The compiler overflow check is passive, or might not even be known about.

Answer (score 2):

Jimi seldom makes answers; I don't know why

> Open up `Project` -> `Properties` -> `Compile`, click the `Advanced Compile Option` button and tick `Remove integer overflow checks`. -- You have the same setting as C# now (which has the same option, but inverted).

If they do post an answer, comment on and i'll delete this one/that one can be accepted

Comment: This works well, though I think the answer from @Craig is slightly cleaner as the developer's intent is clearer.